# What are good investment tools for someone who often moves internationally?

Tags: investing, international

Because I work as a consultant, for the last three years I've been moving to a different country every year: UK, Hong Kong and now Germany. I will probably continue this lifestyle for at least 2-3 year. I don't know in which of those countries, if any, I would eventually want to settle.

It seems that many investment platforms are heavily geared towards a certain country. Hargreaves Lansdown, which I used when I lived in the UK, would not even accept my money after I moved abroad.

Are there any good investment platforms or alternative investment products that work well with my situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactive brokers. It allows you to have a single account to trade stocks and currencies from several countries.